# Discrepancy between iterated integrals

Tags: iterated-integrals

Question

**Consider the function $$f(x,y) = \frac{xy(x^2-y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^3}$$**

**Using the substitution $u=x^2+y^2$ and $du=2y dy$, the following integral becomes**

$$\int_0^2 \int_0^1 f(x,y) dy dx = \frac{1}{5}$$
**Using the substitution $u=x^2+y^2$ and $du=2x dy$, the following integral becomes**

$$\int_0^1 \int_0^2 f(x,y) dy dx = -\frac{1}{20}$$
**Why the iterated integration are giving different results? In other words, why Fubini theorem fails for this integral?**

Is it because both $\int^\infty dy \int^\infty|f(x,y)| dx$, $\int^\infty dx \int^\infty|f(x,y)| dy $ doesn't converge? If so how do I calcualte the integral (it is so hard to calculate it)?

Comment: Maybe you just messed up while integrating? Try putting it into WolframAlpha.

Comment: No, it is correct.

Comment: You posted this question yesterday, no? Remember, for functions of several variables, you need to do a substitution in that many variables, i.e., let $(u, v) = (x^2 + y^2, x^2 - y^2)$ and find the Jacobian.

Comment: Acutally this is the question, that I am supposed to answer that why in this condition is the iterrated integration not working. For that matter of posting the question, i dont think I posted any questions yesterday.

Comment: Nonetheless this change of variables is incomplete.

Comment: Why is that? Can you please explain?

Comment: This question is an exact duplicate of your previous (now deleted) question (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2533882/non-existence-of-double-integrals). $$\int_{I\times J}f(x,y)\,d\mu $$ does not exist because $\int_{I}\int_{J}f(x,y)\,dx\,dy$ and $\int_{J}\int_{I}f(x,y)\,dy\,dx$ are different. In particular $f(x,y)\not\in L^1(I\times J)$. So **the integral** $\int_{I\times J}f(x,y)\,d\mu$ makes no sense.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio That's the question. Why are those two integrals different. Why does Fubini's theorem fail on them?

Comment: @mathnoob123: because the integrand function does not belong to $L^1(I\times J)$, as you prove in your last lines.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Apologies but I am not aware of those terminologies. The method I used was to convert the integral in polar coordinates which became $\int \frac{sin 4\theta}{4r}$ and stated the integral doesn't converge on the provided domain. Would it be okay for a reasoning?

Comment: NO. If a function is not integrable over $I\times J$, the integral over such domain makes no sense, no matter which coordinates you take for describing $I\times J$. You **cannot** compute something which is not well-defined.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69174/discussion-between-mathnoob123-and-jack-daurizio).

Answer (score -2):

Let's go back to calculus I. Suppose you wish to compute

$$ \int_a ^b f(x) \ dx $$

by means of a change of variable $x = g(u)$. Then you'd write $dx = g'(u) \ du$ and (assuming $g$ is one-to-one), the integral becomes

$$ \int_{g^{-1}(a)} ^{g^{-1}(b)} f(g(u)) g'(u) \ du $$

and you proceed as normal.

For functions of several variables, you do something similar, but a full change of variables requires as many variables as there are present in the integral.

My comment said to consider $(u, v) = (x^2 + y^2, x^2 - y^2)$. Why? The objects on the right of the equals sign here appear in the integrand, and just placing $u = x^2 + y^2$ doesn't quite do a change of variables justice, as you need to map $(x, y)$ into $(u, v)$. What you've done was map $(x, y)$ into $(u, y)$, which doesn't really work.

I've mentioned a Jacobian in the comment. This is a scaling factor that is present in a coordinate change. A definition is that if $(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) = (f_1(u), f_2(u), \ldots, f_n(u))$ where $u = (u_1, \ldots, u_n)$ is the coordinate system you're moving into, then the Jacobian $J$ is

$$ J = \left| \frac{\partial (x_1, \ldots, x_n)}{\partial (u_1, \ldots, u_n)} \right| = \det \left( \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial u_j} \right) $$

where the matrix in question is built by taking the derivative of $x_i$ with respect to $u_j$.

Usually the absolute value is taken, so the new volume measure with this change is $dx = |J| \ du$.

Try to follow along [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/ChangeOfVariables.aspx) and compute the integral. I have a feeling it should converge once the right substitution is made.

Comment: The thing is I dont have to find a way to evaluate the value. I have to find the problem with the way we are asked to evaluate.

Comment: The substitution depends on two variables so the limits of integration aren't wholly valid. That's why you do this process.

Comment: What I am supposed to answer is why the Fubini theorem doesn't apply for this probelm

Comment: *I have a feeling it should converge once the right substitution is made.* : not at all. This is not a matter of applying the right substitution or computing a Jacobian. $f\not\in L^1(I\times J)$, so $$\iint_{I\times J}f(x,y)$$ makes no sense. Both $\int_I \int_J f(x,y)\,dx\,dy$ and $\int_I \int_J f(x,y)\,dy\,dx$ are well defined and convergent, but they simply are different things.